# Xcode menu not visible on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, xcode

I installed Xcode from the Apple App Store. I am using Mac OS X version 10.8.5.

I want to install the command line tools using Xcode however I am unable to view the menu. Some articles on the Internet mention that we can access the preferences for Xcode from the menu, however I am unable to view it.

I can view Xcode as a dock item in the tray, when I right click on it, I get the options:

```
Open Developer Tool (this in turn gives more options like Instruments, iOS Simulator, Printer Simulator and so on).
Options (this gives more options like: Keep in Dock, Open at Login and so on).
```

How can I access the preferences of Xcode?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The command line tools are no longer available from an XCode menu item. If you want to install them, you must first download them from the [Apple Developer Website](https://developer.apple.com/).

Comment: I was able to install the command line tools using the Xcode menu and I have Xcode version 5.0.1

Comment: That's strange, I wasn't able to and I guess, neither was everyone who upvoted this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329243/xcode-4-4-and-later-install-command-line-tools